# Connecting to LDAP with PHP Successfully, but cannot connect with C#

Tags: c#, php, ldap

I am connecting successfully to the LDAP with PHP, tried a whole lot of things but when I try with C# am always getting either "Server is not operational" or "The LDAP server in unavailable".
Here is the PHP code:

```
    <?php
function login($username='user', $password='pass') {
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Invalid username or password.');
        }
        if (($ldap = @ldap_connect($url = 'ldap://ds.xyz-example.com', $port = 636)) === false) {
            echo('Error connecting LDAP server with url %s on port %d.');

        }
        if (!@ldap_bind($ldap, sprintf($dn='uid=%s,ou=People,dc=xyz-example,dc=com', $username), $password)) {
            $error = ldap_errno($ldap);
            if ($error === 0x31) {
                echo('Invalid username or password.');

            } else {
                echo('error during authentication with LDAP.');
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


login(); // call the function
?>
```

This is working perfect but I need it with C#. How can I do this with C# using the port and the dn and the user and pass?

Here is what I tried with C# but with an error "Server is not operational"

```
string ldapPath = "LDAP://ds.xyz-example.com:636/UID=user,OU=People,DC=xyz-example,DC=com";
            string user = "user";
            string password = "pass";

            DirectoryEntry deSSL = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, user, password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);
            try
            {
                user = deSSL.Properties["uid"][0].ToString(); //if this works, we bound successfully
                Response.Output.Write("Success... {0} has bound", user);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Output.Write("Bind Failure: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `DirectoryEntry` with AD but for generic LDAP requests you should have a look at `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`. Also found [this blog](https://auth0.com/blog/using-ldap-with-c-sharp/).

Comment: Thanks EricLavault, this blog seems really helpful will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your library doesn't implement LDAP but rather a weird non-standard Microsoft version of LDAP called ActiveDirectory, which only works when the server is an actual ActiveDirectory Server and doesn't quite work as easily when you use non-microsoft servers, such as OpenLDAP?

Could it be?